# TSQL Stored Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a table-valued function, in SQL Server 2012, that makes a call to another table-valued function based on an input parameter, here's an example

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMyLastFilterFunction] 
(   
    @Param1 VARCHAR(64),
    @Param2 VARCHAR(64),
    @Param3 INT,
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    IF (@Param3 = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t1.Col4
        FROM fnMyFirstFilterFunction(@Param1,@Param2) t1
        WHERE t1.DateTimeEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    END

)
```

When I execute this I get two errors:

1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'
2. Incorrect syntax near ')' (i.e. the last closing parenthesis)

Is it possible to have such a condition in a table-valued function?  Basically I'm trying to implement a filter system starting with all data in "**fnMyFirstFilterFunction**".  So **"fnMyLastFilterFunction"** takes that data and filters it by @start and @end date.  I'm using stored functions to separate the filter stages. My SQL is rusty, so if there's a better way of doing this, I'm open to ideas.

UPDATE:

SpectralGhost's suggestion compiled fine, but what if in the function body I want the logic to call different functions based on @Param3's value?  Such as the following:

```
IF (@Param3 = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t1.Col4
        FROM fnMyFirstFilterFunction(@Param1,@Param2) t1
        WHERE t1.DateTimeEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    END
ELSE IF (@Param3 = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t1.Col4
        FROM fnOtherFilterFunction(@Param1,@Param2) t1
        WHERE t1.DateTimeEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    END
```

Comment: You can't use control-of-flow logic in an inline TVF. If you want to explicitly use `IF` you'd need to convert to a multi-statement TVF, but I think the answers are a much better alternative since they allow the function to remain inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the edit, try

```
 SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t1.Col4
 FROM fnMyFirstFilterFunction(@Param1,@Param2) t1
 WHERE t1.DateTimeEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 AND @Param3 = 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t1.Col4
 FROM fnOtherFilterFunction(@Param1,@Param2) t1
 WHERE t1.DateTimeEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 AND @Param3 = 1
```

Since @Param3 will never be both 0 and 1 simultaneously this is logically equivalent to an if statement.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your help, I was trying to think of some way to use a CASE / WHEN, but your solution makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 7):

Get rid of the IF and replace with this query.

```
 SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t1.Col4
 FROM fnMyFirstFilterFunction(@Param1,@Param2) t1
 WHERE t1.DateTimeEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 AND @Param3 = 0
```

Comment: As Brian stated in his answer to the edited question, simply doing a union for each @Param value you need to account for would work.

Comment: Thanks SpectralGhost to both you and Brian for your help and for enlightening me, I've learned something new in the world of SQL :)